# Rails Sunspot Auto-complete Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, sunspot-rails

I have a search form with two fields:

One is: name
Second one is: category

So two models "Post" & "Category"

Category search field is auto complete field so it puts category name.

The trouble I am having is converting category name in to category_id when search form is submitted...

Have been goggling for ages but have not found any answers :(

Comment: Look at this gem https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: Or just use `Category.find_by_name(params[:category])` in create \update action

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you already implemented autocompletion and only need to find category.id by its name? If so try something like this.

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

    def method_where_category_id_needed
        # here you can use category_id
    end

    def category_id
        category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category_name])
        category.id
    end

end
```